Receiving messages from secure rather then twilio number in conversation?
I am building a chat app where Admin creates conversations . The admin email is used as identity to join as participant in the conversation. We add the second participant by its phone number & I have setup the webhooks on twilio number so when the receiver reply on twilio number I intercept the messsage & store in DB and also the messages appear in the conversation.
But when the admin sends the message in conversation using its identity it is received from something secure & not the twilio number. Any suggestions?
I have also set the twilio number in sender pool in twilio messaging service.
    async joinConversationByIdentity(conversationSid: string, identity: string) {
        const options = {
            identity,
        };

        const conversation = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversationSid).participants.create({
            ...options,
        });

        return conversation;
    }

    async joinConversationByPhoneNumber(conversationSid: string, phoneNumber: string) {
        const options = {
            'messagingBinding.proxyAddress': process.env.TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER,
            'messagingBinding.address': phoneNumber,
        };

        const conversation = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversationSid).participants.create({
            ...options,
        });

        return conversation;
    }

    async sendMessage(author: string, message: string, conversationSid: string) {
        const response = await client.conversations.v1.conversations(conversationSid).messages.create({
            body: message,
            author,
        });

        const conversation: Conversation = await this.twilioService.getConversationById(conversationSid);
        const twilioMessage: TwilioMessage = {
            messageSid: response.sid,
            accountSid: response.accountSid,
            conversationSid: response.conversationSid,
            author: response.author,
            body: response.body,
            participantSid: response.participantSid,
            index: response.index,
            dateCreated: response.dateCreated,
            dateUpdated: response.dateUpdated,
            conversation
        } as TwilioMessage;

        await this.create(twilioMessage);
        return response;
    }
}

